# Creating a price calculator function in a Django model

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have this:

```
Class OrderService(models.Model):
       article_deadline = models.IntegerField()
       article_pages= models.IntegerField()
       def price_calc(self):
              if OrderService.article_deadline <= 12
                    unit_price = 35
              elif OrderService.article_deadline>= 13 <= 24
                    unit_price= 30
              else:
                     unit_price= 25
              price_calc()
              return unit_price

        total_cost = article_pages * unit_price
```

It gives an error that unit_price is not defined. I need when the user enters article_deadline in the form, the function determines the unit cost to use and then calculates total_cost. I think I am missing something very simple.

Comment: Remember, that methods in classes can accept Class attributes by self, if you are using Pycharm, IDE can give hints for self objects, and you will not make mistakes in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first you should use `self` instead of `OrderService` and you need to call the function at some point otherwise your `unit_price` will not be calculated since the function never got called. The best way to narrow this kinda things down is using `print("test price_calc")` statements inside the function.

```
Class OrderService(models.Model):
       article_deadline = models.IntegerField()
       article_pages= models.IntegerField()


       def price_calc(self):
         #print("test price_calc") # check if the function ever gets called
         if self.article_deadline <= 12:
            unit_price = 35
         elif self.article_deadline>= 13 <= 24:
              unit_price= 30
         else:
            unit_price= 25
         return unit_price * self.article_pages
```

If you want to use the variable name `total_cost` you can do:

```
total_cost = price_calc
```

and register `total_cost` in the admin / use it in functions, but its the same thing you can as well just use price_calc and it will display/calculate the same value...

You can also see that the function never got called because you should get a Syntax error for `if OrderService.article_deadline <= 12`. You are missing the ":" here and on the next `elif` statement as well.

Comment: It gives an error that price_calc takes exactly 1 argument (0 given). Any advice on this? Thanks so far

Comment: @MailerDaemon check out the code now. It should work.

Comment: Thanks it worked, just did return unit_price * self.article_pages then total_cost= price_calc